# responsive design display none and visibility visable not switching

Tags: responsive-design

Hi all I am making my first responsive website.

I am doing it mobile first.

In my html I have given some elements which I do not want to be shown on mobile a class of mobile and those I don't want showing class of desktop

This is working brilliantly.

When I get to my tablet / desktop breakpoint and I reverse these to show the desktop menu for example, it is not working.

```
.desktop {visibility:visible;} .mobile {display:none;}



<div id="topbar">
        <!--Mobile Nav-->
           <section>

                <div class="mobile container">
                   <div class="col12">

                     <div class="click">Menu</div>

                       <nav id="menu">

                          <li><a href="">home</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">club information</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">club kit</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">membership</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">event news</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">calendar</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">advice</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">gallery</a></li>

                       </nav>
                   </div>


               </div>


           </section>
           <!--Desktop Nav-->
           <section>

                <div class="desktop container">
                   <div class="col12">



                       <nav id="menu">

                          <li><a href="">home</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">club information</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">club kit</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">membership</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">event news</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">calendar</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">advice</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">gallery</a></li>

                       </nav>
                   </div>


               </div>


           </section>
       </div>
```

Comment: Very hard to see how it's meant to be working without the actually CSS code that powers the breakpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is alternate the `.mobile` and `.desktop` classes to be `display: block` or `display: none` as and when you need things to be shown/hidden through out your break points.

You're confusing the use of `display` and `visability` in your current example